# how could I store Big file (30G of like) on an external SD?

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, formatting

I need to store on an android tablet or phone some big file : about 30G. To be read by an app as a database.

but because of Fat32 simple copy just fail after 2G.

Could I format my external SD under linux ext2 ? is NTFS format recognized ? Do I have a chance to carry such a file on an external SD ?

Comment: Generally this is not possible, external storage in most android versions and devices must be Fat32... Can you be more specific as to the device and Android version?

Comment: hi, I am not locked in a device or android version. I need to use kiwix with some ZIM database on some place were no internet is accessible. I can chose a stecific device but I can not reduce the size of the ZIM.

Comment: rooted phone can mount ext4 formatted MicroSD Card

Comment: nice @alecxs , I am not sure a rooted device will fit. still need a hardware guarantee

Comment: i can only guarantee its definitely not possible without modifications. the phones internal storage however can be extended with external sdcard (adoptable storage) but you must not remove this sdcard

Comment: @alecxs is an external USB disk a possible solution ?

Comment: the problem remains the same, you must place the ntfs binaries somewhere. i have found only this without root but does not work for me http://techapple.net/2016/08/how-to-readwrite-to-ntfs-disks-on-usb-otg-in-android-no-root-enable-ntfs-mount-without-rooting https://www.paragon-software.com/free/exfat-ntfs-fat32-hfs-android

Comment: @alecxs it looks a good solution to transfer data. my problem is that I do not have enough space on internal storage so I need a system wide enabled external space. I guess I have to root a tablet. thanks for the links.

Comment: As you mentioned you're developer? of a app, there is a Tutorial about adoptable storage shared from @yoloxolo you might be interested. You should be able to access adoptable storage from your app, this gives you enough space on a ext4 file system https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213312

Comment: I am not a dev. @alecxs

Comment: Did you try `exFAT`? On which Android version and ROM you are? `exFAT` was natively added to Android Pie (not through FUSE): https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/vold/+/refs/heads/master/fs (kernel must have exFAT support). Some custom ROMs do have NTFS support added to vold through FUSE. If your device doesn't support exFAT, you can try this module which replaces stock `vold` binary with a custom one: https://github.com/Magisk-Modules-Repo/vold-posix (requires Magisk root). Also with root access you can manually mount any removable storage with `ext4` filesystem.