# SD card not appearing when formatted as internal

Tags: adoptable-storage

I'm a user of the Realme C2(android P). I've just formatted my SD card as the internal storage through Powershell since my manufacturer doesn't allow me to do it in the settings. It don't think it worked as now i do not see the SD card in the storage section. It seems to have completely disappeared.These are the commands that I used from this [link](https://jimcofer.com/2016/03/10/marshmallow-lg-and-adoptable-storage/):

```
adb shell sm list-disk
adb shell sm list-volumes all
adb shell sm set-force-adoptable true
adb shell sm partition disk:179,64 private
adb shell sm set-force-adoptable false
adb shell sm list-volumes all
```

I really have no idea if they even worked as I was told that the 4th command would take some time but, it didn't. I'll be more than happy to post screenshots or anything that is required for you to understand the problem. So if there is anything you can do to help me, please do so. This is my last resort.

EDIT:

This is what happened in the Powershell window:

```
PS C:\Users\Sa**vik\Downloads\platform-tools> .\adb devices
List of devices attached
EUS4***ZPBTWAM79 device
PS C:\Users\Sa**vik\Downloads\platform-tools> .\adb shell sm list-disks
disk:1*9:1*8
PS C:\Users\Sa**vik\Downloads\platform-tools> .\adb shell sm list-volumes all
private mounted null
public:1*9:1*0 mounted 01*7-1*13
emulated mounted null

PS C:\Users\Sa**vik\Downloads\platform-tools> .\adb shell sm set-force-adoptable true
PS C:\Users\Sa**vik\Downloads\platform-tools> .\adb shell sm partition disk:1*9,1*8 private
PS C:\Users\Sa**vik\Downloads\platform-tools> .\adb shell sm partition disk:1*9:1*8 private
PS C:\Users\Sa**vik\Downloads\platform-tools> .\adb shell sm set-force-adoptable false
PS C:\Users\Sa**vik\Downloads\platform-tools> .\adb shell sm list-volumes all
emulated:1*9,1*0 unmounted null
private:1*9,1*0 mounted c5ee2ab2-9**7-468e-8**6-c700ba9**283
private mounted null
emulated mounted null
PS C:\Users\Sa**vik\Downloads\platform-tools>
```

I'd put in * to keep it anonymous

I'm giving up for now. We'll see what happens in the future

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94680/discussion-on-question-by-yoloxolo-sd-card-not-appearing-when-formatted-as-inter).

Comment: @alecxs the link you gave me doesn't work. I have an issue trying to modify my boot image. It says file image is unsupported

Answer (score 1):

When you format your SD card as internal storage (aka [adoptable-storage](/questions/tagged/adoptable-storage)), it will be encrypted. The key for en/decryption is stored on the device only. Hence all that a PC can see is "there is a partition but I don't know what's on it": as it hasn't access to the key, it cannot decrypt the contents.

For further details, see e.g. our [adoptable-storage tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info) and follow the links from there.

Comment: but that isn't the problem I'm facing! I just can't get the additional memory to show up in my storage settings

Comment: Could you then please update your question and say so? Even the title suggests you're talking about having formatted the entire card as internal and no wonder where it's gone, and neither does the text speak of "partitioning". Not sure if it's part of the commands used, but then only those familiar with them could spot it.

Comment: @Izzy when we talking about adoptable storage issues we should also mention the double encryption problem since Android 9 https://source.android.com/devices/storage/adoptable#fixing-double-encryption

Comment: @alecxs only if it's relevant to the problem (it is not here IMHO).

Comment: @Izzy Yes the card is gone when we look at the storage from my phone. I don't understand why you thought I was looking at my SD card from a PC. The only thing I used a computer for is to convert my SD card into adaptable storage. Plus I haven't mentioned anything about partition as I didn't to the best of my knowledge make any

Comment: If you didn't partition, then the entire card got converted to internal memory – and of course can no longer show up separately. So on-device, it should look like your internal storage has been enlarged, while the external SD card is gone (if I understood that correctly).

Answer (score -1):

Try to plug the memory card into PC and see what is the file system of it. Default format for memory cards is FAT32. Sometimes file systems does gets changed and the changed file system is not compatible with the Android system. It happens a lot of times with USB drives.

Comment: I don't see anything under the file system. Windows thinks the SD card is corrupted

Comment: I dont think Android is uses EXT4 file system for external SD Cards. Instead Android Systems use exFAT or FAT32 for the SD cards.  https://www.all-things-android.com/content/understanding-android-file-hierarchy

Comment: Please note that when formatted as internal storage (aka [tag:adoptable-storage]), the card is encrypted and indeed not formatted FAT but, in most cases, EXT4.