# Why can't I move apps to external sdcard?

Tags: root-access, external-sd, app2sd, 8.1-oreo

I'm using `Redmi 5 Plus` with global Oreo 8.1 ROM, rooted with Magisk. And I can't move my apps to external sdcard.

I tried with native method of Android. But the Redmi 5 Plus or MIUI doesn't seem to have the option to move the apps. So, I used `Apps2SD` app to do the work. It has the option to move with just native method. But it failed with `new installs into ASEC containers no longer supported`. I also tried other apps but the same error.

Comment: MIUI probably just not showing the buttons. you can do it from adb shell https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213312 and then any new installed app should be installed there. if phone is rooted you can force the Migrate Button with `am start -n com.android.settings/com.android.settings.deviceinfo.StorageWizardMigrateProgress` (after following the above tutorial (hidden link))

Comment: The device was rooted. Tried Apps2Sd app. The error said something "the asec folder is write restricted". I tried with other like link2sd too. Same result.

Comment: @IrfanLatif I think the problem is not with any specific app but rather the android itself. But the surprising thing is that why there isn't much commotion about it? Android is really a mess. restricting write access to Ext card already was out of my understanding and now this! I am not sure what you mean by portable or adoptable but my sdcard is what everyone else is using and mounting.

Comment: you can only move apps which allow it in manifest. adoptable storage is the native counterpart for Link2SD. you would knew that if you had read the link

Comment: external MicroSD Card can be splitted in two partitions. one partition remain vfat while the other partition must formatted ext4. The ext4 partition can be treated as internal memory while the vfat partition is still useable as external. of course Link2SD can do more than just native App2SD, but it is the nearly same concept

Comment: i don't use any of this, neither encryption. i never used WhatsApp at all (which is main reason for 90% waste) and i am fine with 10 GB. My girlfriend has just one single bind mount of WhatsApp Media Folder at startup, so all other apps remain at (faster) internal memory while the big WhatsApp garbage is stored on MicroSD. Best stable solution :)

Comment: I once tried creating a 2nd partition of Ext sdcard to transfer whole app with all its data to extsdcard. But I am not talking about that. Now it seems I can't even move the apps with native move method given by the Android. The apk used to be moved to the encrypted "asec" folder. But now it says the write to that folder has been restricted. So, basically no more move to sd is available.