# Micro sd card doesn't show up after I formated it as internal storage

Tags: internal-storage, sd-card, storage, internal-sd

I have the Xiaomi Mi A1 device and has Android 9 running on it. I just bought a new micro sd card cause my internal storage is full. When I first inserted it, I chose the option "format it as internal storage". I migrate the data, but it fails when it got around 60%ish, so I manually move some apps to the sd card from the app settings. However, not all apps has that option. I only able to move apps like Facebook, Ms. Word, etc. But I don't really think of it that much, I guess that's how it is. And now my problem is that, apparently, after I formatted it as internal storage, the sd card doesn't show up in the file manager (I use X-Plore and google files) because I also want to move my photos and videos. Though I was able to move some apps to it through the apps settings.

I tried to format it as normal storage (forgot the option name, "format as portable storage" I think?). It shows up in the file manager, and I can move my photos and videos, but now I can't move my apps to it. So my question is that

1. Is that how it is? When you format a sd card as internal storage, the file manager can't read it? or am I missing any setting?
2. I figured out maybe because my sd card is broken, I bought an SanDisk Ultra microSDHC UHS-I Class 10 and it says up to 80MB/s speed, 533x. Perhaps got a better recommendation?

Sorry for bad english, I'm not native.

Comment: If a new sd-card "breaks" by just using it often it is a fake (sd-card contains less flash than it claims to have). If you have a PC and a micro-sd-card USB reader use one of this tools to test if your card is genuine: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/test-and-detect-fake-or-counterfeit-usb-flash-drives-bought-from-ebay-with-h2testw/

Comment: 1. yes thats normal, there exist no external storage any longer because you have adoptable storage. you can check this from terminal with `df` you will see */mnt/expand/.../media* (which is your MicroSD Card) is mounted to */storage/emulated*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to free Internal Storage by moving data or using symlink / bind-mount with Adoptable Storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/214233/how-to-free-internal-storage-by-moving-data-or-using-symlink-bind-mount-with-a)

Comment: one thing you can do is split MicroSD Card in two partitions (mixed) https://android.stackexchange.com/q/145457 https://android.stackexchange.com/q/213312