# Format SD card for internal storage for POCO M3 Pro

Tags: storage, xiaomi, internal-sd

I recently purchased a POCO M3 Pro 5G.

I also received an SD card which I want to use as an extension to internal storage.

I have looked around here for how to do it and none of the suggestions seem to work.
Using Activity Launcher just doesn't work because the required activity doesn't appear under "Files".

There is no system option to do this.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SD card not appearing when formatted as internal](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213312/sd-card-not-appearing-when-formatted-as-internal)

Comment: if you don't care about warranty you could [root](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50706408#50706408) your device

Comment: @alecxs I would rather not root it. The only reason I got the SD card was because they only had 64GB phones. They said it would work but didn't. In the end, I went back and switched to a slightly more expensive phone with 256GB. Plenty for the foreseeable future.