# SD Card doesn't show up after attempting to format as internal storage from stock crDroid Android 10 Files app

Tags: internal-storage, sd-card, android-10, samsung-galaxy-tab-s-10.5

After attempting to format my SD card as internal storage for Samsung Galaxy Tab S 10.5 LTE (SM-T805) using the preinstalled Files app on crDroid (Android 10), it is no longer recognized by my device. I believe it is now completely corrupt, as even Windows is unable to read it after attempting to use an SD card adapter. It's not even listed in the disk management program.

Please help as I was dependent on my SD card as I only have 16GB on this device.

Edit: after formatting it in twrp it shows up in my device however im still not able to format as internal as some java error comes like i said before...

[image: error right after formatting as internal from settings>storage]

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/LQ82msb
first pic is when the storage is formatted as internal and the second is after doing as external

Comment: please try these adb shell sm commands (from question) and check which one throws the java error (line by line):

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SD card not appearing when formatted as internal](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213312/sd-card-not-appearing-when-formatted-as-internal)

Answer (score 0):

All fine. That is per design. Once formatted MicroSD Card as [adoptable-storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info), it becomes part of your Internal Storage and will disappear. Because it is an encrypted file system, no PC card reader can detect it.

Comment: Well thats the problem it dint become adaptable storage my storage still shows 16gb but the sd card disappeared...coming to think about it a java error was thrown at me after attempting to format but it was one of those disappearing notifs at bottom of screen....